# Spark: Unknown/unsupported param error when setting conf.yarn.jar

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a little application that runs fine on my Spark cluster based on Yarn when I commit it with spark-submit like this:

```
~/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4$ bin/spark-submit --class MyClass --master yarn-cluster --queue testing myApp.jar hdfs://nameservice1/user/XXX/README.md_count
```

However, I would like to avoid uploading the spark-assembly.jar file each time, so I set the `spark.yarn.jar` configuration parameter:

```
~/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4$ bin/spark-submit --class MyClass --master yarn-cluster --queue testing --conf "spark.yarn.jar=hdfs://nameservice1/user/spark/share/lib/spark-assembly.jar" myApp.jar hdfs://nameservice1/user/XXX/README.md_count
```

This seems to be fine at first:

```
15/07/08 13:57:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/07/08 13:57:18 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 24 NodeManagers
15/07/08 13:57:18 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
15/07/08 13:57:18 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
15/07/08 13:57:18 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
15/07/08 13:57:18 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
15/07/08 13:57:18 INFO yarn.Client: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying hdfs://nameservice1/user/spark/share/lib/spark-assembly.jar
[...]
```

However, it fails eventually:

```
15/07/08 13:57:18 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application 670 to ResourceManager
15/07/08 13:57:18 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1434986503384_0670
15/07/08 13:57:19 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1434986503384_0670 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/07/08 13:57:19 INFO yarn.Client: 
 client token: N/A
 diagnostics: N/A
 ApplicationMaster host: N/A
 ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
 queue: testing
 start time: 1436356638869
 final status: UNDEFINED
 tracking URL: http://node-00a/cluster/app/application_1434986503384_0670
 user: XXX
15/07/08 13:57:20 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1434986503384_0670 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/07/08 13:57:21 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1434986503384_0670 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/07/08 13:57:23 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1434986503384_0670 (state: FAILED)
15/07/08 13:57:23 INFO yarn.Client: 
 client token: N/A
 diagnostics: Application application_1434986503384_0670 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1434986503384_0670_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1434986503384_0670_02_000001
Exit code: 1
[...]
```

In the Yarn log, I find the following error message indicating a wrong usage of parameters:

```
Container: container_1434986503384_0670_01_000001 on node-01b_8041
===================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time:Mi Jul 08 13:57:22 +0200 2015
LogLength:764
Log Contents:
    Unknown/unsupported param List(--arg, hdfs://nameservice1/user/XXX/README.md_count, --executor-memory, 1024m, --executor-cores, 1, --num-executors, 2)
    Usage: org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster [options] 
Options:
  --jar JAR_PATH       Path to your application's JAR file (required)
  --class CLASS_NAME   Name of your application's main class (required)
  --args ARGS          Arguments to be passed to your application's main class.
                       Mutliple invocations are possible, each will be passed in order.
  --num-executors NUM    Number of executors to start (Default: 2)
  --executor-cores NUM   Number of cores for the executors (Default: 1)
  --executor-memory MEM  Memory per executor (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1G)

End of LogType:stderr
```

As the same application runs when uploading the local assembly file upon submission, it seems to come down to the assembly file. Could the one on the cluster be a wrong/different version? How could I validate that? What other reasons might be the cause? Is the warning `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: ...` possibly related?

The same happens when I set the (deprecated) environment variable `SPARK_JAR` instead of setting `spark.yarn.jar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking the obvious question here: are you sure the spark-assembly.jar on HDFS is the same one as you have locally? If not, can you try uploading your local spark-assembly to your home directory on HDFS and try again?

Comment: Should have mentioned it, I've already tried that too, same error.

Comment: Can you try submit the spark examples jar and running an example that takes arugment? (e.g. SparkPi) That way we can isolate if that's an issue with your jar or not. Another stupid question is did you package all dependencies into your application jar? If so, spark related dependencies are properly marked as `provided`?

Comment: Turns out there was some mess regarding JVM versions that I am not able to reproduce, sorry.